# System > Configuration > Fatal error: Class ‘Varien_Data_Form_Element_Color’

Tags: configuration

I am trying to access system > configuration but I get the following error ~

> Fatal error: Class ‘Varien_Data_Form_Element_Color’ not found in
>   /home4/trifect1/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line
>   146

Appreciate any help or advice you can offer me.

Thanks!

Comment: The error you posted on Twitter suggests a compilation error. Is this s different issue?

Comment: Hello philwinkle, the suggestion above resolved the issue I was having. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an element in one of your `system.xml` files that has the type `color`. This shouldn't be there by default so either you add it or there is an extension that did.
Search in your `system.xml` files for this piece of text:

```
<frontend_type>color</frontend_type>
```

and remove the field or change the type to `text`.

Comment: Hi Marius, thank you for that suggestion. I will try this and get back to you if it solved the issue.

Comment: Hello Marius, this suggestion worked and resolved the problem I was having. Thank you!

Comment: Same here - that worked.
But should I change this file? Does this just come from my installed theme?

Comment: @Chris. From what I know, this is not present in the core. Most probably comes from a custom extension or theme. So you can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Marius is spot on, here is the file path:

```
\app\code\local\ThemeOptions\ExtraConfig\etc\system.xml
```

A custom theme has overwritten this file in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a 50+ Rep so I cannot comment another answer directly, but it is important to confirm that Ray's answer is correct. The -1 rating is unjustified.

Experienced the same error of the OP, caused by a "Varien_Data_Form_Element_Counter" not found (the OP has "Varien_Data_Form_Element_Color"). The offending code was an extension, so I examined its system.xml and files. Recovered file Counter.php from a backup of the extension and put it in /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed it by adding "Color.php" file into /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element
Just took it from another installation.