# Varien_Data_Form_Element_Color missing in magento 1.9.1

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I see that `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Color` form input type is not found in Magento 1.9.1

Do you know why it was deprecated? Or has this been replaced by something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you have custom extension which is created element for color in this path

```
\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Color.php
```

just add this class to above path.this would be solution.

**EDIT**

you may also you this answer [System > Configuration > Fatal error: Class ‘Varien_Data_Form_Element_Color’](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6241/system-configuration-fatal-error-class-varien-data-form-element-color)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am aware of that, I fixed already. I was curious why was that deprecated.